# sql Select Earliest Date Multiple Rows

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
id    from_date       to_date        empty
 1     24/03/2016      01/04/2016     Y
 1     01/04/2016      23/06/2016     Y
 1     05/08/2016      01/04/2017     Y
 1     01/04/2017      01/04/2018     Y
 1     01/04/2018      01/04/2019     Y
```

The current date falls between 01/04/2018 and 01/04/2019 however, the earliest consecutive date is 05/08/2016.  How can I write an sql script to pick up the earliest from date for the period that includes today.

Is this possible without creating a temporary table and updating the from date for each id? where the from_date = to_date for the previous row.

Hope that all makes sense.

Thanks
Iain

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to group the values together.  Here is one method to get the periods of the continuous dates:

```
select id, min(from_date), max(to_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_to_date = to_date then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(to_date) over (partition by id order by from_date) as prev_to_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

For filtering, you can add:

```
having current_date >= min(from_date) and current_date <= max(to_date)
```

Comment: Thanks however, when I try and run this I get the following error message:

ADF routine found DB-DAT_VALUE with an invalid length